# How to fetch only some fields of an entity having associations using hibernate query?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity which has multiple fields, some of which are associations. 
Assume the entity has similar structure to the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foos")
public class Foo {

  public Foo() {}
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column
  private String name;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
  private Bar bar;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "bar1_id")
  private Bar1 bar1;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "bar2_id")
  private Bar2 bar2;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
  private List<Bar3> bar3;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
  private List<Bar4> bar4;

  //getters and setters
}
```

My question is how can I load only some fields and not the whole entity using Hibernate query?
I want to fetch only id, bar, bar1 and bar3, and don't want to fetch the remaining fields(name, bar2, bar4) in the created Foo object.
I'm pretty new to Hibernate so any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Spring Data is the best solution for these scenarios. Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem with the help of the following [link](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-multiple-entities-same-table/). I've created a new entity FooShort, with the same table name "foos", and containing only the fields required from Foo.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foos")
public class FooShort {

  public FooShort() {}
  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "bar_id")
  private Bar bar;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "bar1_id")
  private Bar1 bar1;

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
  @JoinColumn(name = "foo_id")
  private List<Bar3> bar3;

  //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate 5, Spring 5

You have several options, but the simplest option is to create a simple @Query with the columns/fields you want, see example code from one of my projects.

First and foremost you are not required to create an DTO with the subset fields, I will show options for both and a hybrid version.

Option One: DTO Object with column/field subset.

DTO Repository Code:

```
@Query( "SELECT new com.your.package.name.customers.CompanyDTOIdName(c.id, c.name) " +
        "FROM Company c " +
        "WHERE c.enabled = 1 " +
        "ORDER BY c.name ASC"           )
List<CompanyDTOIdName> compDtoNameWhereEnabledTrue();
```

DTO Subset object:

```
public class CompanyDTOIdName {

    private long id;
    private String name;

    public CompanyDTOIdName(long id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // accessors/mutators methods
}
```

Hibernate SQL execution code:

```
SELECT
    new com.your.package.name.customers.CompanyDTOIdName(c.id, c.name) 
FROM
    Company c 
WHERE
    c.enabled = 1 
ORDER BY
    c.name ASC
            
select
    company0_.companyId as col_0_0_,
    company0_.name as col_1_0_ 
from
    ome_company company0_ 
where
    company0_.enabled=1 
order by
    company0_.name ASC
```

Major disadvantage is that you will require a separate DTO object with every different combination of columns.

---

Option Two: Using original @Entity

Your second option, much simpler and will work with any column subset is as follows:

Repository Code:

```
@Query( "SELECT new com.your.package.name.customers.Company(c.id, c.name) " +
        "FROM Company c " +
        "WHERE c.enabled = 1 " +
        "ORDER BY c.name ASC"
)
List<Company> compNameWhereEnabledTrue();
```

Where Company is your original @Entity object.

Your Entity object must contain empty constructors as well as constructors that match your @Query statement in this case:

```
public void Company() {}
public void Company(Long id, String name) { /* code omitted */ }
```

Hibernate SQL execution code:

```
SELECT
    new com.your.package.name.customers.Company(c.id, c.name) 
FROM
    Company c 
WHERE
    c.enabled = 1 
ORDER BY
    c.name ASC

select
    company0_.companyId as col_0_0_,
    company0_.name as col_1_0_ 
from
    ome_company company0_ 
where
    company0_.enabled=1 
order by
    company0_.name ASC
```

Caution: I'm sure you can see the problem with this approach. Only the indicated columns/fields are loaded. You will get exceptions if you attempt to access non initiated fields.

---

Hybrid Version using Interfaces (Best of both worlds)

Create interface with required accessor fields.

```
public interface CompanyDTOIdNameInterface {
    
    public Long getId();
    public String getName();
}
```

Implement interface on @Entity object.

```
public class Company implements Serializable,
                                CompanyDTOIdNameInterface
{ /* omitted code */ }
```

Repository Code:

```
@Query( "SELECT new com.your.package.name.customers.Company(c.id, c.name) " +
            "FROM Company c " +
            "WHERE c.enabled = 1 " +
            "ORDER BY c.name ASC"
    )
    List<CompanyDTOIdNameInterface> compNameWhereEnabledTrue();
```

Its as simple as that. Good luck :)

Comment: Your hybrid approach is again putting in the same problem, lets say we have 5 such cases with the permutation and combination of the multiple fields. Then how can we create those many interfaces and let us say we need price field in three of them then what?

Comment: @Shivang If you have multiple permutations and loading fields is resource-light (ie primitives/boxed primitives) then load all fields and extend interfaces to cover specific sets. If you are loading fields of type `objects` or `collection<object>` you will have to write `@Query/Interface` for every set of fields. `Query` + `Interface` code is still a lot less code than DTOs, returned obj can also be cast to `Interface` or `@Entity` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be creating a repository that will get the objects by chosen criteria, then extract only the fields that you need from the object list if you are using Spring Data: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

For hibernate only it should go like this:

```
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    Foo foo = entityManager.find(Foo.class,id);

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Or with a custom SQL query, for chosen fields only:

```
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Foo e");
    List<Foo> workerList = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I think the above query will fetch all the fields of foo object from database. What I want is to load only the mentioned four fields into the foo object from db, i.e., the resultant foo object shouldn't get any values for bar2, bar4 from db.

Comment: Modifying the HQL query to should do the trick, i.e. "SELECT e.name FROM Foo e". If you need some help with HQL, here's a tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm. Hibernate also allows to use native SQL queries if you would prefer https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_native_sql.htm.

Comment: I tried that, and for columns which are part of table, this will work well. But for associations, a lot of joins will have to be written which might make the query complex. I was able to solve the problem with help from [this](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-map-multiple-entities-same-table/) link. I've created a new entity FooShort, with the same table name "foos", and containing only the fields required from Foo.